# Knight covering the whole grid?

Tags: optimization

- A knight (the chess piece)
- $m$ x $n$ grid
- Start from any square

**Question:**

For which, general case, $m$ x $n$ (neglecting the obvious failes $m,n=1,2$) is this possible/impossible without visiting the same square more than once? Can you mathematically prove this?

---

My approach has been "guessing" so far. So don't know how to prove it.

Here are some simple examples:

[image]

Obviously you can't start at the mid square and no matter where you start on the periferi the mid square will be left empty.

---

[image]

On this example we can see my approach (1-12) which means it's possible only if we start  at 1,3,5,8,10,12. So this is at least the minimum grid required, $3$x$4$ (least squares involved).

Answer (score 2):

From the wikipedia page of [Knight's tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#cite_note-Cull1978-10):

[Schwenk](https://web.archive.org/web/20190526154119/https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c3f5/e69e771771de1be50a8a8bf2561804026d69.pdf) proved that for any $m \times  n$ board with $m \le n$, a closed knight's tour is always possible unless one or more of these three conditions are met:

- $m$ and $n$ are both odd
- $m = 1, 2$, or $4$
- $m = 3$ and $n = 4, 6$, or $8$.

[Cull et al.](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/16-3/cull.pdf) and [Conrad](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X9200170Q?via%3Dihub) et al. proved that on any rectangular board whose smaller dimension is at least 5, there is a (possibly open) knight's tour.